# Changing emacs python interpreter to Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, emacs, interpreter, anaconda

To change the default emacs python interpreter, I tried to change my .emacs file to something that looks like this `(setq python-shell-interpreter "c:/Users/me/Anaconda3/python.exe")`.

Unfortunately, when I run python code now, the interpreter acts like nothing happened. Any idea on what I should do?
Images in case you have no idea what I'm talking about:
 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/reDaW.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFx9G.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVkg9.png

Edit: I managed to get the Anaconda interpreter to run, but when using matplotlib, the graph does not pop up.

Comment: In the interpreter that came up, try running `xdata`. Does that variable exist? If so, you're defining all the functions but not running whatever "main" function you've defined. Perhaps you have code like `if __name__ == "__main__"` that runs differently under Anaconda?

Comment: It is undefined when I pull it up.

Comment: I got it to work by reinstalling python-mode and changing around python-mode.el's default compiler.